# Регулярное выражение для команды rename

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ubuntu, terminal

Есть много файлов вида `Артикул [какие-то символы].jpg`, так вот как мне их всех переименовать в `[какие-то символы].jpg` командой `rename`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. если в качестве программы `rename` испольуется `prename` (*perl*-овая реализация, чаще встречается именно она), то можно переименовать так:

   ```
   $ rename 's/Артикул //' *.jpg
   ```

   кстати, в этой реализации можно добавить опцию `-n`, чтобы только посмотреть, какие файлы и как будут переименованы:

   ```
   $ rename -n 's/Артикул //' *.jpg
   Артикул [какие-то символы].jpg renamed as [какие-то символы].jpg
   ```
2. если же испольуется реализация из *util-linux*, то можно так:

   ```
   $ rename 'Артикул ' '' *.jpg
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. `rename -n 's/Артикул\ (.*)\.jpg/$1\.jpg/' *.jpg`