# Как изменить названия файлов рекурсивно

Tags: bash, sed

Добрый день.
Мне нужно убрать суффикс от имени файла и добавить префикс в начало файла. Изменить нужно рекурсивно. Пробовал сделать так:

```
 for f in $(find /folder/ . -name "*_file._small.mov*");
 do mv $f $(echo $f | sed '/._small/s/._small//g');
 done
```

но так не работает

`87349_file._small.mov` и превратить в `small_87349_file`

Заранее спасибо

Comment: prename — ваш друг. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/451339/178576 и http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/436355/178576

Answer (score 2):

похожие вопросы:

- [Массовое переименование файлов rename](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/451330/178576)
- [Регулярное выражение для команды rename](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/436348/178576)

---

готовое решение может выглядеть, например, так:

```
find /folder/ -type f -name \*_file._small.mov\* | while read f; do
  d=$(dirname $f)
  n=$(basename $f)
  (cd $d; prename -n 's/\._small\.mov//;s/^/small_/' $n)
done
```

обратите внимание на параметр `-n` программы `prename` — благодаря его наличию переименованы файлы не будут, а будет лишь выдан отчёт о возможных действиях (для действительного переименования этот параметр надо убрать). пример вывода:

```
87348_file._small.mov renamed as small_87348_file
87349_file._small.mov renamed as small_87349_file
```

Comment: Отлично, что есть возможность проверить результат.

Comment: Насколько я помню у find есть ключ -execdir, который позволяет производить операции с файлами в их же каталоге, т.е. теоретически команда будет примерно такая: `find /folder/ -type f -name "*_file._small.mov*" -execdir prename -n 's/\._small\.mov//;s/^/small_/' {} \;`